# For loop equivalent to reduce execution time in pandas data frame operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have written a for loop like this:

```
for i in newc2sdf.Source.unique():
    ydf=newc2sdf[newc2sdf.Source==i]
    for j in newc2sdf.Destination.unique():
        ydf1=ydf[ydf.Destination==j]
```

As I have so many unique records, It takes huge time to execute.

I will do some basic operations from the ydf1 and it will return a single value and I will append the value in a list.

And I want to calculate the sum of values from another column where the source and destinations will be unique.

I have another column called timestamp (ex: 2016-08-01 00:10:01) and it's in numpy.datetime64 format, I want the sum of those where the timestamp will be 5 minutes more than the minimum timestamp for a particular source to destination.

Is there any alternatives to reduce the execution time.

Comment: You are overwriting `ydf1` here on every iteration of the loop. I doubt that's your intention.

Comment: Why do you want a separate dataframe for each combination of Source and Destination? If you give a bit of context around what this will allow you to achieve, it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: I will do some basic operations from the ydf1 and it will return a single value and I will append the value in a list. I just want to reduce the execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following sample dataframe:

```
newc2sdf = pd.DataFrame([['Home','Seattle',3],['Vacation','San Francisco',74],['Work','Portland',9],
                        ['Vacation','Seattle',24],['Work','Portland',4],['Home','Seattle',5],
                        ['Work','Portland',31],['Vacation','San Francisco',19],['Work','San Francisco',38],
                        ['Home','Seattle',85],['Work','San Francisco',32],['Vacation','Seattle',73]],
                        columns=['Source','Destination','Value'])
```

Which gives:

```
      Source    Destination  Value
0       Home        Seattle      3
1   Vacation  San Francisco     74
2       Work       Portland      9
3   Vacation        Seattle     24
4       Work       Portland      4
5       Home        Seattle      5
6       Work       Portland     31
7   Vacation  San Francisco     19
8       Work  San Francisco     38
9       Home        Seattle     85
10      Work  San Francisco     32
11  Vacation        Seattle     73
```

To calculate "the sum of values from another column where the source and destinations will be unique", I would imagine you are looking for `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
newc2sdf.groupby(['Source','Destination']).agg({'Value': 'sum'}))
```

Yields:

```
                        Value
Source   Destination         
Home     Seattle           93
Vacation San Francisco     93
         Seattle           97
Work     Portland          44
         San Francisco     70
```

And finally, if you wanted to store this column of values to a list:

```
newc2sdf.groupby(['Source','Destination']).agg({'Value': 'sum'})['Value'].tolist()
```

Comment: I have another column called timestamp (ex: 2016-08-01 00:10:01) and it's in numpy.datetime64 format, I want the sum of those where the timestamp will be 5 minutes more than the minimum timestamp for a particular source to destination.

Comment: That is a completely different question than the one you originally posted.

Comment: Apology. I was trying using for loop that gives the filtered data frame where I could calculate the rest. But that was taking log time. 
I am looking for some solution like what you posted, I appreciate.